# Can Pandas find all the lines that join any pair of **dots** and don't intersect any of the given **lines** without iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, intersection, lines

Given a properly defined list of **dots**, and a list of **lines**:

Can Pandas find all the lines that join any pair of **dots** and don't intersect any of the given **lines** without iteration?

Im currently reaching to the solution, as you can see in the image, but I must iterate in the process, and that iteration makes everything painfully slow.

In the image, the list of **dots** are the drawn color dots, and the list of **lines** would be the candlesticks. The desired outcome are the black lines.

[image]

Although the question aims for a theoretical solution, or conceptual confirmation if its possible or there is no other way than iterations, here is the code Im currently using, in case it helps:
http://pastebin.com/4DiKVy26

Comment: Is it lines 28 to 34 in your pastebin that you're trying to optimize?  Pandas does *not* have the functionality you're looking for per se, but something with Numpy might be feasible.

Comment: I think you are refering to the "30" and "3", the reason for that is to avoid lines that are further away than 27 steps, to avoid extra calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Pandas, but I can see what you're trying to do, and yes it can be done faster. I'm going to call the black lines *rays* for reasons I hope will become clear; in your algorithm, with m dots and n lines, you are finding all m(m-1)/2 rays, then doing 2n comparisons in order to filter them: m*(m-1)*n => cubic in the size of the input. There is a way to make this quadratic in the input.

What you're describing can be solved by a form of *[raycasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_casting)* (though simpler because it's in 2d): think of the dots as lights; a source dot can only cast a ray to a target dot if the target is not in the shadow of a line. So we start with a dot, and move to the right over a list of lines and dots that you might illuminate. As we pass by lines, there will be an expanding region of shadow; but at any x value, we only need to know the 2 gradients of the shadow's edge to know if a y value is in shadow. As we pass each line going right, update the gradients of the shadow. As we pass each dot, we check if it lies outside the shadow; if it does we have a ray. Repeat this process for each dot, and you are done. This works out as roughly m*(m-1)/2+m*n calculations, which scales a lot better.

Comment: Thanks, Im going to diggest that and test it, will be back as soon as I have results, but looks like what I was searching for. If its so, I will post the pandas version of that.

Comment: I was clearly lacking of a mathematic approach,not a pandas library one, so im accepting this, as said, I will update with the pandas code when I develop it.